# wamp server :Mysql service getting stopped automatically while accessing phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I use Wamp server. when we start wamp server first time, it show shows green icon. but when try to access phpmyadmin, the icon goes to orange color. Apache server working fine. only Mysql service is getting stop automatically.
Even also their is no log generation in MySql log file.
it shows

> ## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

i have gone through various solution but it's not working.

please help if some one facing same problem and having a perfect solution for it.
thanks.

Comment: odd - how did the installation go? Was there anything weird about it?

Comment: Can you access mysql directly over the command line? Maybe your database is damaged.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs the installation was successful without any error. we are facing this problem from yesterday and wamp server is installed one year ago.

Comment: @DineshPAtil hmm odd - maybe try as Hal suggested and see if you can access through the cmd line :) if you can't then mysql is broken and maybe try repairing it :)

Comment: @Halcyon
thanks to both of you. actually one of our database is broken. that why it changes wamp server icon from green to orange, and mysql is getting stopped.

Comment: @DineshPAtil oh man - good luck with that - happy you found the cause though :)